# Plantuml sequence diagram lifeline for async execution

Tags: uml, plantuml

Here is my sample shown also on picture below

```
@startuml
participant "Client" as C
participant "Server" as S
participant "Third Party" as 3PT

C -> S++: request money
S -> S: do I know you?
S -> 3PT++: give me money for client
return here you have money
S ->> S++ #005500: compute usage
S ->> 3PT: notify about computation details
deactivate S
return money
@enduml
```

[image: plantuml image]

Is it possible in PlantUml sequence diagram somehow define the lifeline for **async operation** to **end after** lifeline from which it was started? So in this case I'd like to finish the `compute usage` in green lifeline after return from `request money` lifeline. By that I would say that `compute usage` is asynchronous operation and can end at any time. Don't know whether this is valid from UML point of view though.

Comment: A self-call is never async! You'd need threading for that.

Comment: That is what I thought. So instead of calling `S ->> S++ #005500: compute usage` I should have something like `S ->> ST++ #005500: compute usage` where `ST` is a new thread and also next line should be `ST ->> 3PT: notify about computation details`

Comment: @qwerty_so [this](https://liveuml.com/view/5f92e4ab4796fa7b0d135379) would be ok?

Comment: no this is not fine, the asynchronous message is a reflexive one, it is not sent to "asynch thread" in the same way the synchronous messages was not sent to a thread. The thread support the execution, they do not send/receive messages

Comment: I overlooked the last message on the thread. Indeed that's not ok. @bruno maybe you can post an answer?

Comment: @bilak is my answer useful for you ?

Comment: Related question on the plantuml forum: https://forum.plantuml.net/6998/named-activate-deactivate Sadly, it also has no solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

As I know there is no way for a reflexive message like `S ->> S++:...` or `S ->> S:...` to start from an *OccurrenceSpecification* and finish to an other (and that for a lot of tools, including [mine](https://www.bouml.fr)), so the only way seems to represent the *Server* two times. To clearly indicate it is the same server you can indicate the name the instance, for instance (naming all instances):

```
@startuml
participant "c:Client" as C
participant "s:Server" as S
participant "tp:Third Party" as 3PT
participant "s:Server" as Sagain

C -> S++: request money
S -> S: do I know you?
S -> 3PT++: give me money for client
return here you have money
S ->> Sagain++: compute usage
C <-- S--: money
Sagain-- ->> 3PT: notify about computation details
@enduml
```

[image]

The [norm](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) says §17.12.17.1 *lifelines represent only one interacting entity*, but an entity can be presented by several lifelines :

- [norm § 17.12.17.4](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) (association ends of Lifeline)

> represents : ConnectableElement [0..1] (opposite A_represents_lifeline::lifeline)
> References the ConnectableElement within the classifier that contains the enclosing interaction

- [norm § 17.13.31.2](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) (Owned Ends of A_represents_lifeline)

> lifeline : Lifeline [0..*] (opposite Lifeline::represents)

(notice the multiplicity `0..*`)

---

Out of your problem it is strange to see the message `do I know you?` alone without consequences depending on the result, PlantUML manages *combined fragment alt* to indicate alternatives

Comment: I'd probably indicate the 2nd `s` as a spawn of the first within the name or attach a note. I don't think that you can have two times the same `s` object because it can have only one life line. It represents the "physical execution flow".

Comment: @qwerty_so I edited my answer to insert extracts from the norm)

Comment: Though, still it feels strange ;-) Probably there should go a note with the 2nd life of `s`?

Comment: @qwerty_so of course a note can be added to help the reader to understand there is no error and the two *Server* are the same

Comment: this example strangely uses S++ to activate but doesn't use S-- to deactivate...I will drop an edit